# Error when putting code for setting figure side by side

Tags: errors, pdftex

I'm new in LaTeX and trying to help my friend to fix her document. I use Texmaker 4.1.1. The LaTeX code of her document is as follows

**Main Document:** (Main Document.tex)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating}

\onehalfspacing
\parindent 1cm
\parskip 0.3cm
\topmargin 0cm \oddsidemargin 1cm \evensidemargin 0.5cm \textwidth 15cm \textheight 22cm
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definisi}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\def\R{\mathbb{ R}}
\def\S{\mathbb{ S}}
\def\I{\mathbb{ I}}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\title{Taekwondo}
\makeindex
\date{}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Gambar}
\newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\huge CHAPTER}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\fancyhead[L]{\textsl{Table of Contents}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Table of Figures}
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Figures}
\fancyhead[L]{\textsl{Table of Figures}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\mainmatter
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

**Chapter 2:** (Chapter2.tex)

```
\chapter{{Theory}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\textsl{Chapter 2 : Theory }}
\fancyhead[R]{}

\section{Taekwondo}
\begin{document}
List of protectors
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1.] \textit{Body protector}.
\item[2.] \textit{Head guard}.
\item[3.] \textit{Forearm guard}.
\item[4.] \textit{Hand protector}.
\item[5.] \textit{Shin guard}.
\item[6.] \textit{Groin guard}.
\item[7.] \textit{Mouth guard}.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{dobok.jpg}
  \caption{\textit{dobok}}
  \label{fig:dobok}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{equipment.jpg}
  \caption{Taekwondoin's Protector}
  \label{fig:peralatan}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Taekwondo}
\label{fig:atribut}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

After compiling, I received the following error messages:
[image]
The error occurred when I tried to put code for setting figure side by side. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: don't use `begin{document}` `\end{document}` in chapter2.tex

Comment: @touhami Thanks for the suggestion. I've deleted the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` code as suggested but I still received error message in the figure setting. What is my mistake now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document` environment should only be declared *once* in your document. As such, `main.tex` should have the format

```
\documentclass[..]{...}
% <preamble>
\begin{document}
% <body>
\end{document}
```

and *never* have a

```
\begin{document}
% <body>
\end{document}
```

inside other `.tex` files you `\input` or `\include`.

Your error is replicated in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}% Outer document environment begin
\begin{document}% Inner document environment begin
\end{document}% Inner document environment end
\end{document}% Outer document environment end
```

The second (inner) `document` environment - `\begin{document}` - causes the

> LaTeX error: Can only be used in the preamble.

Comment: I've deleted the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` code as suggested but I still received error message in the figure setting. What is my mistake now? +1 anyway

Comment: @Venus: Remove the [`subfigure` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) from your preamble; [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) already provides this functionality (in a far superior form). Moreover, `subfigure` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. It perfectly works. Can I ask you one thing. Why when I edited the code and ran it, the pdf output still load the previous version (before editing). I've edited many times but my editing didn't show up in the pdf output.

Comment: @Venus: That shouldn't happen, unless you didn't save the edits.

Comment: I did save it but still ... Is there a bug in my tex compiler?