# Aligning text in bullet style

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, itemize

I want to format my article like the picture below:

[image]

**Raw text:**

```
 Before scientists can develop medicines or engineers can advance
 technology, they throw numbers onto whiteboards using concepts laid
 out by mathematicians sometimes centuries earlier. Generations of
 school children will disagree, but no other field of study has played
 a bigger role in changing the course of history as mathematics. We've
 identified the 20 mathematicians responsible for the modern world.

 Issac Newton   :   While not exactly obscure, this list would be
 incomplete without a mention of Sir Issac Newton, the English luminary
 of the Scientific Revolution. Newton developed early physics, a
 scientific method, the theory of universal gravitation, and
 calculus...

 Gottfried Leibniz  :   Invented infinitesimal calculus independent of
 Englishman Sir Issac Newton. His notation is still widely used
 today...

 Leonhard Euler :   A Swiss mathematician who spent most of his life in
 Russia, Leonhard Euler is considered the preeminent mathematician of
 his generation...
```

It's easy to use MS Word to do it but I don't know how to do this using LaTeX. I have tried online search but I can't find any TeX sites discuss this matter. It crossed my mind to use this code

```
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item
\end{itemize}
```

but it didn't yield the format like I want. What kind of code should I use to produce the format like the screenshot picture specially using the little square bullet, not the circle one?

Comment: Please, note that Newton's name is Isaac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` package and tweak things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand{\mysquare}{\scalebox{0.5}{\raisebox{0.65ex}{$\blacksquare$}}}
\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{\strut\smash{\mbox{}\hspace{\parindent}\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\mysquare \, \raggedright#1\hfill :}}}
\begin{document}
  Before scientists can develop medicines or engineers can advance technology, they throw numbers onto whiteboards using concepts laid out by mathematicians sometimes centuries earlier. Generations of school children will disagree, but no other field of study has played a bigger role in changing the course of history as mathematics. We've identified the 20 mathematicians responsible for the modern world.
%
\begin{itemize}[align=myleft,labelwidth=3.5cm,leftmargin=\dimexpr3.5cm+\parindent+\labelsep\relax]
  \item[Issac Newton]  While not exactly obscure, this list would be incomplete without a mention of Sir Issac Newton, the English luminary of the Scientific Revolution. Newton developed early physics, a scientific method, the theory of universal gravitation, and calculus...
  \item[Gottfried Leibniz] Invented infinitesimal calculus independent of Englishman Sir Issac Newton. His
      notation is still widely used today...
   \item[Leonhard Euler]  A Swiss mathematician who spent most of his life in Russia, Leonhard Euler is considered the preeminent mathematician of his generation...
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. I have defined a square using `amssymb` package. This is resized and raised a bit using `\scalebox`  and `\raisebox` commands (from `graphicx` package).
2. Defined an alignment for the argument of `\item` as `myleft` with an appropriate width (3.5cm here, adjust suitably).
3. Used `myleft` as alignment and tweaked `labelwidth` and leftmargin` suitably. If you change 3.5cm, change it here too.

---

To change square to numbers or alphabets you can change the code as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}
%\renewcommand{\themycount}{\arabic{mycount}}  % for numbers
\renewcommand{\themycount}{\alph{mycount}} % for alphabets


\newcommand{\mysquare}{{\refstepcounter{mycount}\bfseries\themycount.}}
\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{\strut\smash{\mbox{}\hspace{\parindent}\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\mysquare \, \raggedright#1\hfill :}}}
\begin{document}
  Before scientists can develop medicines or engineers can advance technology, they throw numbers onto whiteboards using concepts laid out by mathematicians sometimes centuries earlier. Generations of school children will disagree, but no other field of study has played a bigger role in changing the course of history as mathematics. We've identified the 20 mathematicians responsible for the modern world.
%
\begin{itemize}[align=myleft,labelwidth=3.5cm,leftmargin=\dimexpr3.5cm+\parindent+\labelsep\relax]
  \item[Issac Newton]  While not exactly obscure, this list would be incomplete without a mention of Sir Issac Newton, the English luminary of the Scientific Revolution. Newton developed early physics, a scientific method, the theory of universal gravitation, and calculus...
  \item[Gottfried Leibniz] Invented infinitesimal calculus independent of Englishman Sir Issac Newton. His
      notation is still widely used today...
   \item[Leonhard Euler]  A Swiss mathematician who spent most of his life in Russia, Leonhard Euler is considered the preeminent mathematician of his generation...
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). I used your code but I got the following errors: `Undefined control sequence. \SetLabelAlign` and `You can't use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode`. FYI, this article I type in Chapter 2, it's separated from the main page.

Comment: @Venus As I can't reproduce that error with above code, you might have to provide a MWE showing your problems.

Comment: I created my document like [this OP](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257831/82877), there are 2 files: Main Document and Chapter 2. I put the above article in Chapter 2. The error occurred when putting this code `\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{\strut\smash{\mbox{}\hspace{\parindent}\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\mysquare \, \raggedright#1\hfill :}}}`. Where should I put this code? In the main or chapter 2?

Comment: @Venus You should put it in preamble i.e., before `\begin{document}`

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work. See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wSy41.png) for the details.

Comment: Anyway, I got the same errors when I paste your LaTeX in a single document. See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KA4IN.png). I use TeXMaker 4.1.1.

Comment: @Venus: You need to add `\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,graphicx}` too.

Comment: I did, please see the cited links in my comments

Comment: @Venus Perhaps you have an outdated version of `enumitem`. Try updating it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for your advice and thanks for your answer Harish Kumar, the code now perfectly works in my TeX editor after I updated my MikTeX to the newest version. Once again thanks :-)

Comment: Harish, how do I change the 'blacksquare' in bullet mode with number or alphabet? It turns out that I should use number or alphabet instead of 'blacksquare'. Would you please help me out? Thanks

Comment: @Venus: I have updated the answer.