# Error in aligning text in bullet style

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

This is follow-up question from [my previous OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260998/82877). I want to format my article like the picture below:

[image]

I create my document like [this format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257831/82877) and I put the above text in Chapter 2. [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260999/82877) gave me the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand{\mysquare}{\scalebox{0.5}{\raisebox{0.65ex}{$\blacksquare$}}}
\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{\strut\smash{\mbox{}\hspace{\parindent}\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\mysquare \, \raggedright#1\hfill :}}}
\begin{document}
  Before scientists can develop medicines or engineers can advance technology, they throw numbers onto whiteboards using concepts laid out by mathematicians sometimes centuries earlier. Generations of school children will disagree, but no other field of study has played a bigger role in changing the course of history as mathematics. We've identified the 20 mathematicians responsible for the modern world.
%
\begin{itemize}[align=myleft,labelwidth=3.5cm,leftmargin=\dimexpr3.5cm+\parindent+\labelsep\relax]
  \item[Issac Newton]  While not exactly obscure, this list would be incomplete without a mention of Sir Issac Newton, the English luminary of the Scientific Revolution. Newton developed early physics, a scientific method, the theory of universal gravitation, and calculus...
  \item[Gottfried Leibniz] Invented infinitesimal calculus independent of Englishman Sir Issac Newton. His
      notation is still widely used today...
   \item[Leonhard Euler]  A Swiss mathematician who spent most of his life in Russia, Leonhard Euler is considered the preeminent mathematician of his generation...
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

When I ran in my TeX editor (TeXMaker 4.1.1), I got the following error:

[image]

I thought the problem is with my TeX editor, so I tried the exact same code in my friend's TeX Editor, TeXMaker 1.9.9a (SVN 1057), the same errors still occurred but the pdf file can still be rendered. Here is the output:

[image]

My question is how to fix the error or how to get the format like the first picture without getting any error?

---

**UPDATE :**

I finally found the problem after discussing this problem in chatroom, I found out my MikTeX is outdated. I have updated to the latest version and now the code perfectly works in my TeX editor. Thanks for your comments and answer. I really appreciate it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: That's strange. I can't confirm your error. Your code produces the desired output on my computer (ubuntu14.04, Texmaker 4.1).

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 and so is my friend

Comment: @Venus: What version of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) do you have? See [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)

Comment: It works on Windows 8.1 snd recent 64-bit MikTeX (with recent `enumitem`)

Comment: The code should work with rather old versions of enumitem. So either you don't have enumitem at all, or some broken local version of enumitem. Show your log-file.

Answer (score 2):

To know which version of `enumitem` is installed in your distribution try with this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\edef\ver{\csname ver@enumitem.sty\endcsname}
\begin{document}

enumitem version

\ver

\end{document}
```

The last version of `enumitem` is 3.5.2 if not try to update it